# I have to make a call in server uploading multipartData but i got this problem

Tags: flutter, file, multipart, multipartfile

This is my code but i get this error :

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:
> Content size exceeds specified contentLength. 17282 bytes written
> while expected 398.

```
 uploadFile(File imageFile,String id,LoginResponseModel responseModel) async {
 var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));

 var length = await imageFile.length();

 var uri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL+"/jobs/"+id+"/signatures/");

 Map<String, String> headers = { "Accept": "application/json",
   "content-type": "application/json",
   "Authorization": "Bearer " + responseModel.access};

 var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

 request.headers.addAll(headers);

 request.fields['name'] = 'test';

 var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('signature', stream, length,
     filename: basename(imageFile.path));

 request.files.add(multipartFile);


 var response = await request.send();

 print(response.statusCode);

 response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
 });

   }
```

Comment: can you try  `var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('signature', imageFile.asStream(), imageFile.lengthSync(),filename: basename(imageFile.path));`

Comment: asStream is not imported

Comment: can you please elaborate your error